# Using PowerShell how to I split the string of a selected property

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am very new to PowerShell and I can't seem to find a solution to the the question about splitting my selected properties value in powershell which works for me.

My current code without the split is:

```
((get-Acl 'c:\temp').Access | where {$_.IdentityReference -like '*\*'} | Select IdentityReference
```

The purpose is to get a list of users who have access to a folder.

the results give me the domain and the user.

Domain\username

and I just want the username as it will be used in a further SQL query to look up details.

so I figured the best way to do it was to split the returned string on the  '\' and take the 2nd value of the array it creates.

so far I am not getting any results back.

Comment: `(Get-Acl 'c:\temp').Access | select -ExpandProperty IdentityReference | foreach { $_.Value.Split('\')[1] }`

Comment: Great! When you're selecting properties, remember to be aware of each property type. In this case, [IdentityReference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.identityreference.aspx) is not a string like you were expecting. If in doubt pipe the result to [Get-Member](https://ss64.com/ps/get-member.html) to see what you're working with.

Answer (score 2):

You can create custom results with Select-Object:

```
(get-Acl 'c:\temp').Access | where {$_.IdentityReference -like '*\*'} | Select @{n='User'; e={$_.IdentityReference.Split('\')[1]}}
```

Comment: Yep, silly me. Copy and pasted from the OP. I'll fix it

Comment: Think that got it.

Comment: So, it seems to partially work.  it produces blank lines now the length of my result set.

Comment: So I probably fat fingered something. I am doing this off the cuff because I don't have time to test it right now. You might try parenthesis around the split.

Answer (score 1):

In **PSv3+** you can take further advantage of [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375), combined with `Split-Path -Leaf` (which, as in [WayneA's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51450357/45375), is repurposed to extract the last `\`-separated component from a `<realm>\<username>` token):

```sh
(Get-Acl c:\temp).Access.IdentityReference | Split-Path -Leaf
```

Note that I've omitted the `where {$_.IdentityReference -like '*\*'}` filter, because - as far as I can tell - *all* `.IdentifyReference` match this pattern (with the first `\`-based token either being a domain name, a machine name, or a literal such as `NT AUTHORITY` or `BUILTIN`).

Also, this outputs an *array of strings* containing usernames only - whereas a `Select-Object` call *without `-ExpandProperty`* would output *custom objects* with the specified (possibly calculated) property/ies instead.

In **PSv4+**, you can make the command slightly more efficient by using the [`.ForEach()` collection *method*](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/10/22/foreach-and-where-magic-methods/):

```sh
(Get-Acl c:\temp).Access.IdentityReference.ForEach({ ($_ -split '\\')[-1] })
```

Answer (score 0):

EBGreens answer is spot on, but I like to use split-path

You can do something like:

```
(get-Acl 'c:\temp').Access | where {$_.IdentityReference -like '*\*'} | Select @{name="UserName";Expression={$_.IdentityReference | split-path -leaf}}
```